# need specific style of pagination using CI pagination technique

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, pagination

i have done pagination using CodeIgnitier pagination library successfully. problem is here i want pagination styling in different format other than what CI provides in cusotom style

CI gives **1 2 3 >>**

but i want in the following style

**1-10 out of 11,593**

please guide me regarding this..

Answer (score 0):

See **1 2 3 >>** is an actual pagination whether we can't say **1-10 out of 11,593** as a pagination, because this gives us information on a particular page. 
Here is a question about **1-10 out of 11,593** this style how can you move from 1st page to lets say 5th page? (The answer is no.) 
I have customized CI pagination library in my previous company pagination showing like this:
"**1 2 3 >>                                               1-10 out of  100             (Here dropdown for list of all pages)**" 
You can also customize that CI pagination library its not anyway tough task. It will take maximum two hrs.

Answer (score 0):

For creating pagination you need the total rows so you already have the information you need for half of the style you need.

for the `1-10` part . Query URI segments with `$this->uri->segment(x)` whatever segment you need and accordingly generate the text .

For generating the forward and backward links have a constant and add/subtract that to the current uri segment that you retrieved earlier generate links .

Or you can customize the pagination library.